# Data transfer from Google ADs to Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api, google-cloud-data-transfer

I have set up a data  transfer from google ads to big query.
I expected to see all the assets in the CampaignAssetStats table.
Howeve, some assets dont appear.

Could anybody please help?
Does anybody have had a similar issue?

I have tried to increase the refresh window to 30 days, but nothing changed.